# Vue Child Component Doesn't Update on Prop Change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-binding, components, vue-props

I'm updating an 'exercise' prop that gets sent to a 'workout' component in Vue. In the child component, I'm emitting a function to increment the set you're on. The function is firing in the parent component (I'm getting console.logs()), but the child component isn't re-rendering.

### The Parent:

```
<ExerciseListItem
  v-for="(exercise) in exercises"
  v-on:completeSet="completeSet"
  v-on:selectExercise="selectExercise"
  v-bind:exercise.sync="exercise"
  v-bind:isActiveExercise="exercise.slug === activeExerciseSlug"
  v-bind:key="exercise.slug"
/>
```

### The methods:

```
methods: {
  completeSet: function(slug) {
    console.log("complete-set", slug);
    const exercise = this.getExerciseBySlug(slug);
    exercise.completedSets++;
    if (exercise.completedSets === exercise.totalSets) {
      this.completeExercise(slug);
    }
  },
  completeExercise: function(slug) {
    this.getExerciseBySlug(slug).isComplete = true;
    console.log("COMPLETE-exercise", slug);
  },
  getExerciseBySlug: function(slug) {
    return this.exercises.find(exercise => exercise.slug === slug);
  },
  selectExercise: function(selectedSlug) {
    this.activeExerciseSlug = selectedSlug;
  }
},
```

### The Child Template

```
<li
  v-bind:class="{ 'white-box': true, complete: exercise.isComplete }"
  v-on:click="exercise.totalSets > 1 ? $emit('selectExercise', exercise.slug) : $emit('completeSet', exercise.slug)"
>
```

[Here's the project on Github](https://github.com/rosswhitehouse/lift-tracker)

[And a live demo](https://lift-tracker.netlify.com/)

Help appreciated

Comment: The value of `exercise.completedSets` should update as expected and also trigger re-renders. What could prevent this if the 'exercie' object itself is not reacitve (has no setter/getter for its properties). In your code it is unclear where the exercise objects are originating from - could you explain or post the code?

Comment: You should enable Vue dev tools for your demo. This would help us debug.

Comment: Hey @TimWickstrom, totally didn't know that was a thing. I've added it now 

Comment: @MarcRo The original data is passed down to the route as props. The original data is in default.js

Comment: @RossWhitehouse I see, I didn't have time to check the repo before. The problem is that your nested objects in your props (the arrays) are not reactive. Vue does not make nested properties reactive by default - hence it can not detect when their values change. You can do two things: 1. explicitly make your props reactive or 2. manually force an update.

Comment: Hey @MarcRo, thanks for that! How do I make the props reactive? Got a docs link or something? Cheers

Answer (score 6):

The component is not updating because the nested values of your `prop` are not reactive, hence, vue does not notice they are changing.

### How to make nested properties reactive in Vue

The following applies to all state in your vue app - no matter whether it is located in a vuex store, your `data()` option, or inside a `prop`.

By default, vue only makes state reactive if it is declared. That means dynamically (at runtime) assigned state is not reactive (e.g. `mounted() { this.bar = 'two' }` will not create a reactive property `bar` in your `data()`).

#### If you want to dynamically create reactive state there are two rules you need to follow:

1. All properties need to be set with `Vue.set(rootObject, key, value)` (e.g. `mounted() { this.$set(this, 'bar', 'two') }` - `this.$set()` is an alias for `Vue.set()`). Read about it here: [Vue Doku](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set)
2. Arrays need to be filled with native array properties (`Array.prototype.push()`, etc.). Setting array elements by index will not make these elements reactive. *Note:* `Vue.set(rootArray, 1, value)` also will not work - as it sets the element by index. Read more about it here: [Vue Gotchas](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @MarcRo. I've implemented the fix here. Fortunately the exercise prop is an object, so all I had to do was change the function so it uses this.$set:

```
completeSet: function(slug) {
  const exercise = this.getExerciseBySlug(slug);
  this.$set(exercise, "completedSets", exercise.completedSets + 1);
  if (exercise.completedSets === exercise.totalSets) {
    this.completeExercise(slug);
  }
},
```

But it still isn't updating, but the vue devtools show the props are. I've pushed changes and I'm not outputting the completedSets next to the title.

Comment: Sorry, there was some bad code in there, here's what I've got right now:
```
completeSet: function(slug) {
      const exercise = this.getExerciseBySlug(slug);
      const exerciseIndex = this.exercises.indexOf(exercise);
      const newExercise = {
        ...this.exercises[exerciseIndex],
        completedSets: this.exercises[exerciseIndex].completedSets + 1
      };
      this.$set(this.exercises, exerciseIndex, newExercise);
      this.$forceUpdate();
    },
```

Which is working, but that's down to forceupdate, which I'd rather not be using

Answer (score 1):

If needed you can call this.$forceUpdate() in the parent component after the emit, which will force a re-render.

Not sure the underlying problem on why your child component is not triggering the update automatically.

Answer (score 1):

@MarcRo's answer is right, but I want add another solution. Because:

> The component is not updating because the nested values of your prop
> are not reactive, hence, vue does not notice they are changing.

, assuming that you are mutating the object being passed to the child component as a prop, sending a deep copy solves the issue because it is the whole object that changes rather than a nested value.

Here is a way to create a deep copy of an object:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))
```